# SAPUI5: Showing pie chart or Bar chart using OData service from HANA DB

Tags: sapui5

I am working on SAP HANA Development project where I need to develop an UI application using SAPUI5 and Odata service.

I need a help on getting the data from HANA table and display in the Pie or Bar Chart.
I am getting the data to a table(oTable) using odata service but not able to display it in the Pie Chart.

Please find below the code snippet:

```
{
var oModel = sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel('link of the .xsodata' false);
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({tableId: "tableID", visibleRowCount: 10}); 
oTable.setTitle("Transactions"); 
oTable.setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindRows('/Transactions');

var dataset = new sap.service.visualization.dataset.SimpleDMDataset();
dataset.setDataTable(oTable);

var pie = new sap.service.visualization.chart.Pie("myPie", {
    width: "700px",
    height: "400px",
    allDeSelectable: true,
    legendFirst: true,
    selectionMode: 'single',
    legendDirection: 'right',
    title: 'Transactions',
    titleHorizontalAlign: 'center',
    subTitle: 'Q1 - 2012',
    subTitleHorizontalAlign: 'center',
    showTitle: true,
    defaultSelectedSliceIndexes: [5],
    legendFormatString: ['0.00%'],
    tooltipTextFormatString: ['0.00%'],
    tooltipMainValueFormatString: ['#,##0'],
    tooltipSubValueFormatString: ['0.00%'],
    showLegend: true,
    pieType: 'pie',
    dataset: dataset
});

pie.placeAt("uiAreaForMyControls");
}
```

Please help me in getting the Pie chart displayed with the data as I am new and in learning phase.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed you were trying to use sap.service.visualization charts with datasets, different to previous answer, here are a couple of simple examples using Northwind OData services

[JSBin: Viz Pie Chart example](http://jsbin.com/detupe/1/edit)

[JSBin: Viz Bar Chart example](http://jsbin.com/teyur/2/edit) - more advanced uses a filter on dataset

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following is a very simple Pie Chart using the NorthWind OData service, same format as XSODATA

It shows the percentage of Products per Category an Expand is used to get the CategoryName - [live demo](http://jsbin.com/bivil/1/edit)
[image]

```
var sURI = 'http://services.odata.org/v3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/';
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sURI, true);


// Pie Chart
var oChart = new sap.makit.Chart({
    width : "100%",
    height: "80%",
    type : sap.makit.ChartType.Pie,
    legendPosition : sap.makit.LegendPosition.Top,
    valueAxis: new sap.makit.ValueAxis({}),
    categoryAxis: new sap.makit.CategoryAxis({}),
    category : new sap.makit.Category({
        column : "category",
    }),
    values : [new sap.makit.Value({
        expression : "products",
        format : "number",
    })],
});
oChart.addColumn(new sap.makit.Column({name:"category", value:"{Category/CategoryName}"}));
oChart.addColumn(new sap.makit.Column({name:"products", value:"{ProductID}", type:"number"}));
oChart.setModel(oModel);
oChart.bindRows({
     path: "/Products",
     parameters: {select: 'ProductID,Category/CategoryName',expand: 'Category'}
});
oChart.placeAt("content");
```